# Acrobat Pro DC launches multiple times on Mac

Tags: macos, pdf, adobe

I'm working with a system that has Adobe Acrobat Pro DC 19.010.20069 installed, on a Mac running High Sierra 10.13.6. When Acrobat is launched it proceeds to open multiple copies of itself, repeatedly, until the system has to be force rebooted. Other Adobe apps run fine, including the free Acrobat DC Reader and the entire Creative Cloud suite.

To troubleshoot, I first tried removing all Acrobat preferences and support files in the following locations:

```
 ~/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Acrobat/
 ~/Library/Preferences/Adobe/

 /Library/Application Support/Adobe/Acrobat/
 /Library/Application Support/Adobe/Acrobat DC AMT/
 /Library/Application Support/Adobe/Acrobat DC Helper Frameworks/
 /Library/Preferences
```

This had no effect. We then completely uninstalled and reinstalled Acrobat, also to no effect. Does anybody have any suggestions as to what to try next?

[image: Acrobat multiple launches]

Answer (score 1):

uninstall/reinstall rarely fixes anything at all, as it doesn't touch the prefs, only the application.

See if clearing the application saved state helps - `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.adobe.[acrobat].savedState`

I don't have Acrobat, so that file path is generic for Adobe products.

Comment: Good suggestion, I deleted that data but it didn't make any difference. I also tried creating a new user account on the Mac, this also didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Update: I was able to reach Adobe tech support by phone (not easy), and we managed to solve the problem using the Adobe Acrobat Removal Tool. Available here:

https://labs.adobe.com/downloads/acrobatcleaner.html

After removal a reinstallation was successful and worked normally.